# RxJs custom operator cant access 'this'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I created a custom operator that access the `this` but it seems that it's always undefined, even though I passed to the function `this` with `bind`

custom operator

```js
function shouldLoadNewOptimizationData() {
    return filter(function([p1,p2,p3]) {
       // some logic
       if(){
          this.store.dispatch()...
       }
    })
}
```

custom operator usage

```js
effect = createEffect(()=> this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(//action type),
    withLatestFrom(
        //...selectors
    ),
    shouldLoadNewOptimizationData().bind(this),
    // more operators..
    )
)
```

Comment: Why don't you declare this function as part of the class definition of the instance you are wanting to access through `this` ?

Comment: Also, you are executing the function before binding it. You should not use parenthesis before the bind   i.e:  `shouldLoadNewOptimizationData.bind(this)()`

Comment: This isn’t how you dispatch actions in an effect. You should just return them https://medium.com/@amcdnl/dispatching-multiple-actions-from-ngrx-effects-c1447ceb6b22

Comment: @Adam, I am returning an action the ```if``` statement is side effect

Comment: @TjadClark I wanted to create a utility function that can be used in other operators.
but the solution with ```shouldLoadNewOptimizationData.bind(this)()``` worked!.
Thank you

Comment: @OrShalmayev - you just hit the nail on the head with your own words - what you actually want is a new effect, not an operator. This is why it's "hard" to find examples of what you're trying to do, because you're doing it against the principles of the library.

Comment: @Adam you're correct.
I refactored my effects to make it without these side effects.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Generally a rxjs custom operator is in the way

```
function myOperator<T>(source: Observable<T>) {

  ...some logic...

  return source; //or return source.pipe(....)
}
```

Or with arguments

```
function myOperator<T>(...args) {
  return function<T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    ..some logic..
    return source //or return source.pipe(....)
  };
}
```

See this [great link](https://netbasal.com/creating-custom-operators-in-rxjs-32f052d69457) about this

Comment: Hi, as far as I know, it's also possible to create custom operators like in my example.
in the article, they also provide an example as I provided.

```javascript
function filterNil() {
  return filter(value => value !== undefined && value !== null)
}
```

Comment: @OrShalmayev it is, but it’s antithetical. Learn to use the library the way it was intended and it will be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the store to `shouldLoadNewOptimizationData`. This way you avoid having to bind `this` every time you use the function:

```
function shouldLoadNewOptimizationData(store) {
    return filter(function([p1,p2,p3]) {
       // some logic
       if(){
          store.dispatch()... // -> use the provided store instead of `this.store`
       }
    })
}
```

```
effect = createEffect(()=> this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(//action type),
    withLatestFrom(
        //...selectors
    ),
    shouldLoadNewOptimizationData(this.store),
    // more operators..
    
);
```

Comment: This isn’t the way the library is supposed to be used. Effects are just supposed to return actions.

Comment: The question is not about wheter or not the filter should use the store to dispatch . That's another discussion on which I completely agree with you. However, you don't know the OP's use-case, and this question doesn't concern that issue. 
The OP's question is on HOW to access the store, not IF he should access the store.

Comment: Nowhere in the [effects docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects) is there an example provided of accessing the store from inside the effect because the fundamentally goes against the design of effects. Learning to use a library properly gets you farther than "just let me write it the way I want write now".

Comment: Scroll down in the docs you linked to, see the `collection.effects.ts` example. The store is indeed accessed from inside the effect, (line 14). Let it go.

Comment: To select from, in a `dispatch: false` effect. Which is not the case here. If you dug deeper into the OPs question, [what you'd find out is that they didn't want to create an operator at all, what they wanted to create was another effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also, `this` current holds the store, the OP's solution is to re-binding their operator to a different this. What a mess this creates

Comment: Your answer was the most appropriate out of all the other ones up to this point, though. Sorry I can't retract my downvote until the answer is edited.

Comment: No hard feelings. The answer was ment to show Inversion of control using function parameters as an alternative to binding 'this'. You're absolutely right about the correct use of NgRx Effects in particular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250436/discussion-between-yadejo-and-adam).

Answer (score 0):

Change to arrow function

```
function shouldLoadNewOptimizationData() {
    return filter(([p1,p2,p3]) => {
       // some logic
       if(){
          this.store.dispatch()...
       }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. 
I'm still getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go **full** angular 15 (who needs `this`, decorators, ngmodules, constructors, ...)

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
...

const shouldLoadNewOptimizationData = () => {
    const store = inject(Store)

    return filter(([p1,p2,p3]) => {
       // some logic
       if(){
          store.dispatch()...
       }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you.
I'm using angular 12, is there a way to implement it?

Comment: Not sure which version this'll work from but if you can import inject from '@angular/core' then this should work.

Comment: Effects aren’t supposed to know about the store, you should just return actions from them, conditionally is fine.

Comment: @Adam sure, that's the custom. Some people break it though, I don't judge. This is a comment for OP, not this answer.